# Stop user input from expanding the text field

Tags: java, android

I want to disallow the user from being able to expand the the text field as shown in the image. It should look like the Password field however both will allow the following to happen with space bar or the return key.

[Text field expansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IIDT.png)

Comment: Have you set the number of lines to 1? Like singleLine="true" in your xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `all` padding to something like `2dp` then set `maxLines` to something that wont overlap the text. Maybe `2` or if you only care for 1 line, then set `singleLine=true`.

Your XML for that `TextView` can look something like so:

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="200dp"
   android:text="Hello World"
   android:id="@+id/txtSomeIdForTextView"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
   android:padding="2dp"
   android:textSize="16dp" />
```

Take a look at this article to get started with UI, old but still good:
https://mobiforge.com/design-development/understanding-user-interface-android-part-1-layouts